# Converting backends to modules. I.e. going from WAR to EAR structure

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We are in the process of converting our appengine project that uses backends to one that uses modules instead. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/converting

This implies going from a WAR project to an EAR project.

However the appengine eclipse plugins only has support for pointing out a WAR directory.

Does anybody know how this work. I.e. should we point this to our EAR directory?

Comment: so currently you make a WAR for your project and can't pack that WAR into an EAR?

Comment: As stated the appengine eclipse plugin has support for pointing out the WAR directory. Now we need to go from WAR to EAR.

Comment: This seems like a misleading question to me. You linked to a page that tells you how it's done... what you're actually looking for is help with the Eclipse plugins. Am I right?

Comment: ??? Google states that to convert backends to modules you should convert the project from a WAR to an EAR structure. However the google appengine plugin lacks support for EAR as I understand it. So the question is what to do!

Comment: Currently you will need to build and deploy via an external script, as GPE doesn't support modules yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We faced the same problem when migrating from backend to modules.
it seems that currently the GPE doesn't support modules, how ever we did solve this with this hack:

We renamed our WAR directory to "default" (you can point the web application there (under Project Properties -> Google -> Web Application -> WAR Directory).

We also included a dispatch.xml file in that module's WEB-INF dir that tells appengine which module to serve according to urls.

the last thing we had to do is to have a custom script that compiles gwt/class to those directories and deploys to appengine.

here is the overview of the project's layout change:

OLD LAYOUT

- project_main_dir

  - war

NEW LAYOUT

- project_main_dir

  - default

    - WEB-INF

      - dispatch.xml
  - module1

    - WEB-INF
  - module2

    - WEB-INF